# Is there a Same-Origin-Policy for links in HTML?

Tags: html, http, security, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

This may sound weird, but let me explain:

I would like to create an HTML page, that contains **content from and links to only  the same domain,** like images etc. I want it to include also (somewhat trusted) external (3rd party) JavaScript, like Bootstrap, jQuery etc., which I link from a CDN.

Now I want to make sure that these other libraries never, under no circumstances, create clickable links (or do XHR-Requests) to other resources than those on my origin domain. So, whatever the user does on this page, requests will only go to my domain, never somewhere else, thus **enforcing links to go only to targets on the same origin domain as the original file was served from**.

- Does this sound reasonable?
- Will it help if I host those (somewhat
  trusted) 3rd party libs on my domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP), which can block everything except `<a href>`.

For links, you could use a `MutationObserver` to watch all links & throw an error or remove invalid links, and you can override `window.open()` to throw an error for invalid URLs.

Comment: Wow, this looks like exactly what I need.